# BeautifulSoup - conditional export to csv

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'd like to see if a site is using Wordpress. And then export the outcome to a csv.

My code below works fine when I don't include the conditional statement (**if find_wordpress:**). But when I require the condition that wordpress has been found to export to csv, the code breaks. I only want to print to the csv if the html is actually found.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

response = requests.get("https://variety.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
find_wordpress = soup.find_all(content="WordPress.com")

with open('try10.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['URL', 'STATUS']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

#if find_wordpress:
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'URL': "https://variety.com/", 'STATUS': "PRESENT"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try It:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
url="https://variety.com/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
find_wordpress = soup.find_all(content="WordPress.com")

with open('try10.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['URL', 'STATUS']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    if find_wordpress:
        print("Its Wordpress")
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'URL':url, 'STATUS': Wordpress"})
    else:
        print("Its not Wordpress")
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'URL':url, 'STATUS': "No Wordpress"})
```

Comment: Hi @small-atom

Thanks so much for your response!

Unfortunately it didn't quite work out as expected. It worked fine for a positive response. But the csv broke for a negative response....

Comment: Edited. Now its shoud be ok

Comment: Thanks @small-atom! That works perfectly. I'm really grateful for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Still playing around with this.

a) When I put a non-Wordpress site (keap) into the URL field it generated a csv, but it was broken.

b) Is there a way to write to csv without a print statement? Maybe if I tried using including 2 conditionals? For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
url="https://keap.com/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
find_wordpress = soup.find_all(content="WordPress.com")

with open('try15.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['URL', 'STATUS']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

if find_wordpress:
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'URL':url, 'STATUS': "WORDPRESS FOUND"})
else:
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'URL':url, 'STATUS': "NO WORDPRESS"})
```